# Cannot connect to redis server running in a different network namespace

Tags: redis, network-programming, tcpdump

**Setup:**

- created a network namespace.
- created a `veth` pair `vetha` and `vethb` with `vethb` end in the
  namespace and other in the host.
- added an ip `192.168.122.50` to the `vethb`
- Started a `redis` server in a container in that network namespace

Sending requests to the `redis` server directly from the client running on same host named as `secondaryvm`. However, it throws : `Failed to connect to Redis: Connection timed out` error. Cannot understand why is this happening, so looked at `tcpdump` stream by sniffing on `vetha`, same is posted below:

```
21:48:33.764967 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31361, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34540 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xe169), seq 3863373484, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417390465 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:48:38.884975 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.122.50 tell secondaryvm, length 28
21:48:38.885101 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.122.50 is-at 1a:8c:7f:8b:4d:e0 (oui Unknown), length 28
21:49:16.138726 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29195, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xe563), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417432839 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:49:17.156952 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29196, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xe169), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417433857 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:49:19.173031 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29197, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xd989), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417435873 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:49:22.405182 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.122.50 tell secondaryvm, length 28
21:49:22.405262 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.122.50 is-at 1a:8c:7f:8b:4d:e0 (oui Unknown), length 28
21:49:23.429054 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29198, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xc8e9), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417440129 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:49:31.621030 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29199, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xa8e9), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417448321 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:49:47.749024 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29200, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0x69e9), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417464449 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:50:20.261084 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 29201, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    secondaryvm.34544 > 192.168.122.50.6379: Flags [S], cksum 0x75d6 (incorrect -> 0xeae8), seq 550142628, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3417496961 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
21:50:25.381045 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 192.168.122.50 tell secondaryvm, length 28
21:50:25.381176 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 192.168.122.50 is-at 1a:8c:7f:8b:4d:e0 (oui Unknown), length 28
```

Redis server is up and the client is getting connected to it according to the `terminal` output but not according to the `tcpdump` output. according to `tcpdump` output, client is trying to connect but didn't achieve the connection establishment successfully.

**Terminal output at the client side:**

```
========================100==================================================
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sw::redis::TimeoutError'
  what():  Failed to connect to Redis: Connection timed out
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Client's code(written in redis-plus-plus):**

```
int main(){
    auto redis = Redis("tcp://192.168.122.50:6379);
    sleep(5);
    int ep = 100;

    while(true){
    cout<<"===================="<<ep<<"======================\n";

    auto pipe = redis.pipeline(false);
    for(int i=1; i<=500; i++){
        string s = to_string(i);

        if(i%2 == 1){
           pipe.set(s, s);
        }
        else {
           string st = to_string(i-1);
           pipe.get(st);
        }
    }

    auto pipe_replies = pipe.exec();
    pipe.discard();


   }
```

According to the terminal's output, it successfully established the connection.

Cannot understand what is happening here.

1. Is it like line `auto redis = Redis("tcp://192.168.122.50:6379");` doesn't establish the connection?
2. redis-server is surely up then why the connection is not established looking at the tcp stream?

Redis version `6.0.9` and IT IS running on port 6379.

How to prevent this error?

**EDIT:**

I've followed below steps/commands to set up network namespace:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ip netns ls
sudo ip netns add alpine_network
sudo ip link add name veth-host type veth peer name veth-alpine
sudo ip link set veth-alpine netns alpine_network
sudo ip netns exec alpine_network ip addr add 192.168.122.50/24 dev veth-alpine
sudo ip netns exec alpine_network ip link set veth-alpine up
sudo ip netns exec alpine_network ip link set lo up
sudo ip link set veth-host up
sudo ip route add 192.168.122.50/32 dev veth-host
sudo ip netns exec alpine_network ip route add default via 192.168.122.50 dev veth-alpine
```

Comment: What is the IP address and subnet  of `vetha` and what is the subnet of vethb?

Comment: @LiamKelly How to see that? I've added exact steps i followed for setting network namespace in the EDIT section. Please look at it.

Comment: Redis client and server are on the same host.